# what happed to image viewer in 21.04? Missing options like delete, rotate and save

Tags: image-viewers

There's no menu so to speak anymore.  I used the one in 12.04 LTS and it was MUCH better.

The arrow keys are missing at the top, but keypad arrows work.

How do you rotate an image and save?

How do you delete a file within image viewer?

These options were available, now gone?

I wish image viewer could re-size an image,  Far-fetched idea, I suppose?

Comment: Which image viewer are you using ? Try Mirage its has basic editing tools to resize/crop/rotate/flip install via apt

Comment: What file types to resize `.png` files? It might help to [edit] your question with more detail.

Comment: I don't know which program you're talking about (you weren't specific; I liked `gpicview` in 12.04 days, still do though the program devs now work on `lximage-qt` as that one was ported from GTK2 to Qt5).  If you're talking about `eog` (eye of gnome or the GNOME image viewer)  it's menu items are found in the dots option just like all other modern GNOME programs  (non-viewer options were also reduced; it's a viewer don't forget).

Comment: OK, what I did find out is that the options I was looking for are well-hidden.  Context menu for one.  To resize, I had to type a control character.  Way back many years, I used the PC program IRFranview.  It was a swiss army knife.